# Keeping microsoft word table rows together per page break

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a form that I'm filling out programmatically using XSLT. I've laid out the form using tables so that the rows will expand downward on overflow. However I'm having an issue keeping the rows together. My question is, does anyone know of a way to mark certain sections so that they will stay together if there is a page break. I'd like to do this as a word setting rather than try to calculate something in xslt.

My word document is formatted similar to:

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|            Row 1                           |
|--------------------------------------------|
|  _____________                             |
|   Signature                                |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Where if enough information is printed the form becomes

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|            Row 1                           |
|--------------------------------------------|
|  _____________                             |
                                               <-- Unwanted page break
|   Signature                                |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

Edit: I'm using word 2003

Comment: [Keeping Table Rows Together](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T003590_Keeping_Table_Rows_Together.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I removed your link. Please do not link to files. It is a security risk and we are not going to download the file. This is a Q&A site not a forum where we will fix your file for you. Please add to your post what you have tried and what version of Word you are using.

Comment: Searching for "word table rows keep together" give plenty more links to read :)